# How can I create a pie-chart with gnuplot?

Tags: charts, gnuplot

I want to create a pie-chart. Is that possible with gnuplot and how to realize that?

Comment: ...many years later. You might want to check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55943348/7295599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/05/simple-pie-chart-with-gnuplot.html) an example of a pie-chart created with gnuplot. Also, on the same site, you can find [another example](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/05/another-simple-3d-pie-chart-with.html), including the script used for creating the pie-chart.

Comment: the links are no linger available :(

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot is a "function plotting program". If you can come up with a function that has pie-like characteristics, Gnuplot will plot it for you. But I doubt that this would be done easily.

I'm afraid the answer is: No, that's not possible.

Edit: Apparently, that's also what the [Gnuplot FAQ says](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00065000000000000000).